# DMA transfer RAM-to-RAM

Tags: c, windows, x86, dma

A friend of mine has told me that on x86 architecture DMA controller can't transfer between two different RAM locations. It can only transfer between RAM and peripheral (such as PCI bus).

Is this true?

Because AFAIK DMA controller *should* be able between arbitrary devices that sit on BUS and have an address. In particular I see no problem if both source and destionation addresses belong to the same physical device.

Comment: Why to copy RAM from one location to another? x86 has a memory paging sistem, so any memory page can be visible in virtual memory at any address.

Comment: Please update this question with your experiences that you have had since then

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ISA (remember? ;-) DMA chips certainly have a [Fetch-and-Deposit](http://cires.colorado.edu/jimenez-group/QAMSResources/Docs/DMAFundamentals.pdf) transfer type.

However, from the [MASM32 forums](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=10759.0;prev_next=prev):

> Hi,
>
> Checking in "The Undocumented PC",
>   he says memory to memory DMA is
>   possible.  He then goes on to say that
>   there can be problems, limitations,
>   and that the CPU can do the copy
>   faster than the DMA hardware anyway
>   (MOVSD on 386+).
>
> So it seems to be a yes you can,
>   but who cares, kind of thing.
>
> Regards,
>
> Steve N.

Comment: Wow! This is interesting. Now I see why there *may* be problems with such a transfer. It can't be done in a single cycle... But OTOH there're modern architectures where you have a so-called "dual memory channel". Here you **can** read+write in a single cycle, can't you?

Comment: Anyway, dual-cycle transfers may be slower. However during such a transfer the CPU may be used for something else. Isn't there a reason anyway to do such a transfer via DMA?

Comment: `Here you can read+write in a single cycle, can't you?` I'm not a hundred percent positive on this, but apart from other feasibility traps, I would imagine that this feat is only possible if the modules are unganged, so they provide separate buses and the source and destination areas reside on two separate memory modules. This would severely limit its usability.

Comment: `Isn't there a reason anyway to do such a transfer via DMA?` Well, it is better to avoid copying altogether. Even if you don't, it might be worth to note that as things stand currently, CPUs can consume data much faster than the memory subsystem can provide. Since you keep the memory controller occupied, there might smaller savings than you intuitively expect. E.g. I/OAT (http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/i/oat) provided 10% savings in CPU utilization on receive and none on send when it was benchmarked.

Comment: I seem to recall from "The Undocumented PC" that it involves taking the old x86 DMA channel reserved for memory refresh and stealing that for half of the transfer, while using the 1 normally free channel for the write portion.  Not an issue as it causes a refresh by using it, but on old hardware that requires it to do the refresh, do NOT forget to set it back to default after the move or you'll rapidly encounter memory issues!  :-)

Comment: What it I have 2 CPU with 2QPI direct links and 1QPI indirect link through bus? Can I concurrently use both DMA copy and memcpy copy to achieve ultimate bandwidth of all times?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, memory to memory transfer is possible well up to 80386 family I have tried with "modern" x86's :)

Specify RAM for source and destination. You might have to watch out for coherence of the L1 cache depending on the device you are programming and if you have enabled the cache.

You might find some code in the Linux kernel for refreshing video RAM pages in shadow memory. This rings a bell.

Comment: Does it work with PCI/PCIex? How does one "watch out for coherence"? Does the memory controller chip in fact do the DMA?

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely DMA engines that cannot transfer between 2 ram addresses, so the second part of the question is already based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: What do you mean by "DMA engines"? Do DMA controller specifications vary for different chipsets based on x86?

Comment: I interpreted your second (or third, if you count the one-liner) paragraph as a general statement. I don't work with x86 ones, but I definitely have encountered powerpc dma controllers that cannot perform ram-to-ram transfers, which is why I made that statement.